# Angular bind sum of properties to property

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to create a simple bill generator.
I have a list of products with a description, unit price, quantity and global amount for each.

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products.list">
    <td>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.description">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" step="1" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" required="required">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="product.unitPrice" required="required">
    </td>
    <!-- Missing the amount -->
</tr>
```

I have a list in my component for the biding:

```
products: [{description: '', quantity: 0, unitPrice: 380, amount: 0}]
```

Now my problem is that I want to bind `product.amount` to `product.quantity * product.unitPrice`. I know I can just do something like this to display it :

```
<td>
  {{ product.quantity * product.unitPrice }}
</td>
```

But I want the value to be bound in the component so that I can use it later, to generate the grand total with all products for example (I have a button to add more).
I also know that I can use event binding and make it so that each time either `product.quantity` or `product.unitPrice` changes, I update the value of `product.amount`, but I assume that with such a high level framework there is a way to make such a simple task 'cleaner' and less verbose than that. Kinda like you do with `{{ product.quantity * product.unitPrice }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options that i know of:

1. what you kind of explained (do this is what i would do), use ngModelChange on each input (price and and quantity) that triggers a function that calculates the total and saves it on the object
2. if you had this in a subcomponent you could implement doChange and it would notify you that a input has changed and you could trigger the recalulation.
3. could implement the doCheck (fires on every change detection so it would be the slowest) and manually check if the values changed.
4. would not recommend it. but you could even call a function in the template that would save the value off when it renders it. (problem is it will recalc on every change detection making it even slower than docheck)

Comment: I ended up creating a ```Product``` class and using setters on the ```quantity``` and ```unitPrice``` fields to update the amount. Works like a charm, and I find it more elegant than using event ngModelChange

Comment: I agree ... i have used that solution too ... specially when i am managing my own ngmodel.